# Rake task's access to web app's global variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am writing a simple Ruby on Rails app with very little knowledge of ROR. The app is to periodically query Twitter and Instagram, fetch the feed for certain users and store them someplace which it can then quickly access when a request for a particular user's tweets or photos arrives.

I was thinking of writing a rake task that will do the part of periodically fetching the tweets and instagram photos.

If the webapp is using a global variable to fetch the feed from, can the rake task access this same global variable and update it?

Or is it a must to use a database so rake and the webapp can update/access the same data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rake task will usually run in it's own process, so it cannot share state with your main app. What you could do however is create a class in your app that fetches the feed and stores it with a timestamp. Whenever that timestamp expires, it will create a new request. However, while easy to implement, this will cause your request to slow down a bit whenever a request arrives after a cache has expired, because the app will need to fetch data from Twitter and Instagram as part of the request.

Comment: what do you think of writing a controller whose sole purpose is to fetch the tweets and photos and update the global var with the new data. Then have a cron job periodically invoking a curl to trigger the controller?

Comment: Also, if I do the controller + cron, will that make the webapp busy and cause regular requests coming to it to queue up? Do the rails servers run several threads to process requests or a single thread? Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: That depends entirely on deployment configuration. As the cronjob is running on the same computer as the rails server proces, it can potentially slow down your http performance, by eating up resources. In practice, a task like the one you describe will only consume minimal CPU resources. With a cron/rake task, you will have to store your data in a local database and have the rails server access that database.

Comment: I forgot to comment on your first question. Invoking a cache refresh using curl sounds like a practical solution as long as you are only running one rails server process.

Comment: Thanks Niels. So I implemented the controller and cron job that triggers it every 15 minutes. Seems to work fine. A question - in your opinion should I be worried about concurrent access of the cache which is a global variable (a hash map)?

Comment: No. When your cron job invokes refreshing using curl, it occupies the rails server process. Requests are handled sequentially, so no new requests will be processed until your request, which updates the hash, is completed.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all your help. You've been incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct your rake task's dependency to load your Rails app then you have access to all the same data your Rails app does.

```
desc 'My polling rake task'
task :twitter_pool => :environment do
  m = MyModel.find(123) # access models
  MyModel::CONSTANT
  ... # etc.
end
```

The "=> :environment" is the important part.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? If the constant is defined as part of the rake task, it should only exist within the process that runs the task. No?

Comment: As Neils B says you can't share state so this won't work as you needed, I misread your question. Your best bet is to poll and cache as Neils descibes

Comment: I tried something like this, but the global vars were not the same when the same code was called from the webapp and when it was called from the rake task. So I believe Niels and Peer are right.